# Selecting elements from a list with nulls

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have this list

```
preRowLocalizer[27]={Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, \
Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, {0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, \
Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, \
Null, Null, Null, Null, Null}
```

But I want to get only the element of the form

```
{0,....,0,1,0,...,0}
```

I tried using the command Select[preRowLocalizer[27], # != Null], but it is not giving me any output. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Use `=!=` instead of `!=`, and report back.

Comment: I tried that and it is giving me only an empty set {}.

Comment: `Select[list, # =!= Null &]` works for me; what did you put in?

Comment: With the additional & works, do you know why that is needed?

Comment: Look at the docs for `Select[]`; pay attention to the "Basic Examples".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
First[DeleteCases[preRowLocalizer[27], Null]]

First[preRowLocalizer[27] /. Null -> Nothing]

First[Cases[preRowLocalizer[27], _List]]
```

All the above give

> `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`